# Assembly: return value of __p___argv

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, argv, calling-convention

I am just staring to learn assembly and reverse engineering. I know this is a very basic question, but still I am not 100% sure if I have got the right answer. `__p___argv` returns the arguments passed to the program and stores the return value in `eax`.
My question relate to the code:

```
call    __p___argv
mov     edi, [eax]
```

- As I understood `eax` would contain the memory address of `argv[0]`, is this correct?
- `argv[0]` is not actually the first parameter passed by the user but something else, and the parameters passed by the user start at `argv[1]`?
- Since `[eax]` would access memory at location specified in `eax`, the value of `argv[0]` is moved to `edi`?

Comment: All your questions depends on what calling `__p___argv` does on your platform. That's not a standard function as far as I'm aware so you'll have to refer to any available documentation. Otherwise, you'll have to deduce what the actual types being returned are by inspecting the memory addresses that you're suspecting it's returning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VC++, `__p___argv` is declared as follows:

```
__declspec(dllimport) char***    __cdecl __p___argv (void);
```

In MinGW, `__p___argv` is declared as follows:

```
extern char***   __p___argv(void);
```

In both cases, the function returns a pointer to a location that contains the address of the `argv` array (i.e., the address of the first element) in `eax/rax`.

The first parameter passed by the user is always argv[1] and the address of this parameter is stored in the second element of the `argv` array. So you'll have to first dereference `eax/rax` and then add 4/8 bytes to the resulting address to get to the address of the first parameter passed by the user.

You can alternatively use `__argv`, which is a variable that is equivalent to   `*__p___argv()`.